# How to migrate Analytics data captured during the phase of migration?

Tags: upgrade

I am trying to upgrade a Sitecore environment for one of our customers from `9.0.2` to `9.1.1`.

For this, I have set up a parallel upgraded environment. Now we will soon be switching the servers.

One issue that comes up is that if any user is registered in the gap ( i.e. the time take to upgrade the environment..around 2-3 days) and the analytics data captured will be lost.

How do I migrate this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the upgrade for the xDB Shards from 9.0.2 to 9.1.1 is very simple:

- run the upgrade SQL script - a matter of seconds
- rebuild xDB index - a few minutes tops (let me know if this isn't the case for you)
- rebuild reporting DB - a few hours tops if you [have this patch applied](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/224364). Does not impact go-live as you can rebuild and it will capture new analytics at same time.

Therefore the best approach to minimise loss of data would be to do the xDB shard copy / restore / upgrade as a go-live activity as part of the cutover. If you can rehearse this you can get it down to a reasonable time. Perhaps as an additional mitigation you can disable any critical forms / functionality (e.g. unpublish the page and publish a maintenance page).